# Brunch build gives error

Tags: javascript, brunch

I'm trying to setup environment for web application that using branch.

After

```
npm install -d
```

I do,

```
brunch build
```

But, receiving following error:

```
27 Jul 12:08:28 - error: [Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Development\Projects\PathToProject/node_modules/brunch']
```

If I just create a new project with `brunch new proj`, build works fine.

I would appreciate any ideas, why it might not work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with installing and running on a Win machine, but that sounds suspiciously like brunch is a local install - is there a way you can determine if it's a local or global install? Are there such things on a PC env?

Comment: thanks for helping. I believe I found solution, I just needed to run npm install inside /node_modules/brunch folder. It start to work after..