# Error when building brunch with banana pancakes

Tags: node.js, npm, brunch

I created a brunch project with the banana pancakes skeleton

```
brunch new brunchtest -s github://Anaphase/brunch-banana-pancakes
```

Then when building I get an error

```
cd brunchtest
brunch build

 -> error: { [Error: Cannot find module '/media/sf_C_DRIVE/wamp/www/test/brunchtest/node_modules/clean-css-brunch'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

So its obvious that some modules are missing but why? The strange part is that when I create the project I see that these modules are downloaded and put into node_modules but then they are removed during the creation process and only these remain:

[image]

Here's the whole npm-debug.log file, I see there are some errors but I don't know what they mean
http://pastebin.com/E4eMFeiC

**Update**
Here's a screenshot of the installation process errors (which should be in the logfile but I guess this is more convenient)

[image]

Comment: Q: What is your OS?  Linux?  Q: Does this link help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684834/brunch-build-gives-error?

Comment: +1 for best title in SO history.

Comment: @paulsm4 I'm running Ubuntu (virtualbox in windows hence the path) @ Undo: Haha, thought exactly the same

Comment: OK: did you do the install in the Ubuntu VM?  Check out the link I cited above.

Comment: @paulsm4 Yes, the install is on the VM but i created the brunch project (brunchtest) on the windows drive thats mounted in the VM. I now tried creating the project on the local virtual maschine drive and it actually built without any problems. So the VM seems to be the problem, I have no idea why though. Thank you so far, now atleast I can build!

Comment: what happens after you execute `npm install` and do the rebuild in brunchtest dir?

Comment: @PaulMiller Same thing, all the dependencies are downloaded and put into node_modules, then during the installation they are deleted. There are some errors though (updated post)

Comment: Looks like it might be this symlink bug in Virtualbox hosted on Windows: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10085

Comment: @MarcKirkwood Nice find! That was the problem. Apperently it's not a bug but a "fix" for a security issue that disables symlinking. I ran `VBoxManage setextradata VM_NAME VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate 1` like one of the comments proposed and now its working. Feel free to post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per MrAzulay's comment, there's a security setting in Virtualbox that disables symlinking. He says he's had success with the following command, which I haven't tested:

```
VBoxManage setextradata VM_NAME VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate 1
```